# Spritekit - Scene created in .sks file is blank when transitioning from another scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I have a main menu scene where when a button is pressed it should transition to another scene.  It appears to transition properly but when it's done transitioning the 2nd scene is blank.  I put breakpoints in the 2nd scene's didMove function and it appears to be running properly.  I know the 2nd scene works properly when directly opened from the GameViewController.  I'm not sure why it's blank when transitioning from another scene.  Here is my current code:

```
class StartScene: SKScene {

  var playButton = SKSpriteNode()
  let playButtonTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueRoundedButton")

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    playButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: playButtonTex)
    playButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)
    playButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    self.addChild(playButton)
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
      let pos = touch.location(in: self)
      let node = self.atPoint(pos)

      if node == playButton {
        if let view = view {
          let transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
          let scene:SKScene = PoolScene(size: self.size)
          self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the scene transitioning to:

```
class PoolScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  var ballPoke : SKSpriteNode?
  var ballBlue : SKSpriteNode?
  var ballOrange : SKSpriteNode?


  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = borderBody

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    ballBlue = childNode(withName: blueBallName) as? SKSpriteNode
    ballOrange = childNode(withName: orangeBallName) as? SKSpriteNode
    ballPoke = childNode(withName: pokeBallName) as? SKSpriteNode


    ballBlue?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = blueBallCategory
    ballOrange?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = orangeBallCategory
    ballPoke?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = pokeBallCategory
    borderBody.categoryBitMask = borderCategory


  }
```

Comment: You are specifing the size in your init scene, not the name of sks file. let scene:SKScene = PoolScene(size: self.size) --> overwrite size with name init

Comment: try and reduce your code,  you can simplify your if statement,  `if node == playButton ,let view = view { ` If it is Swift 3.0, if it is < 3.0 use `if let view = view where node == playbutton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the wrong init method to load your PoolScene. The way you do it is for when you are not using the Xcode visual level editor. 
Like your GameViewController, you need to init scenes with a reference to the corresponding .sks file.

```
 if node == playButton {
     if let view = view {
        let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)

         if let scene = PoolScene(fileNamed: "PoolScene") {
              view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
         }
      }
  }
```

or in a slightly cleaner way

```
  if node == playButton {
     let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)

     if let scene = PoolScene(fileNamed: "PoolScene") {
         view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)    
      }
  }
```

"fileNamed:..." is the name of the .sks file for your PoolScene, which you usually give the exact same name as the .swift file. Use guard or if let because it will return an optional.

As a small tip, make use of swifts type inference to make your code a bit nicer like in my example.

Hope this helps

Comment: just small fyi,  if you plug your code into his code, it will break due to view being local and no longer being an optional, and you are not using self.view?

Comment: This is the code from 1 SKScene to another SKScene. I never use self unless I have too. Yeah didn't see that he is unwrapping  view already. Should just be view in that case. I will update my answer.

Comment: I know, but look at the OP code,  he has `if let view = view`